# Is it Possible to so.?

Tags: vb.net, printing, printdocument

I have searched lot regarding this. But there is no complete solution. 
In my form i want to print the document upto the information contained in 
my print document page (avoiding paper wasting instead of printing the whole page). 
At the same time i should pass only one page [ie. i want to say paper height as 
long as my data existing.so there is no possiblilty for next page]

**Methods Used :**

**1. Using Print Document :**

In OnBeginPrint Event

```
  Dim xCustomSize As New PaperSize("Custom",820, 100)
        xCustomSize.PaperName = PaperKind.Custom

        With Me.DefaultPageSettings
            .PaperSize = xCustomSize
        End With
```

**2. Without using print Document :**

i followed below reference

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/110314/POS-Printing-The-Easy-Way

In method 2 i didn't initialize the paper height.but it takes the default height as
something. and if the data exceeds,it continuous in next page.

I'm Using :

```
 Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
  Printer : Roll Paper Printer (Model : Bar Code Printer TT033-50)
```

Can Anyone help how to resolve this issue.

Comment: @HansPassant i'm using vb.net coding.. i've some doubts with the coding in the link you have send..  what is equalent data type for 'any' in vb.net in the below coding                 Private Declare Function WritePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal _
         hPrinter As Long, pBuf As Any, ByVal cdBuf As Long,  _
         pcWritten As Long) As Long

Comment: @HansPassant i've changed 'any' as 'object'. but it's not working..that links it says that this coding applies to visual basic versions.. so can i use that coding in vb.net?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322090

Comment: @HansPassant i also used above link coding.. here the text document is not getting printed. if i open the printer properties, that document is present with status printing.. but nothing comes out

Answer (score 1):

The closest to the requested implementation would probably be to do either...

**A**

1. input (and store/track) the length of the roll<sup>**1**</sup> when replaced, a receipt is reprinted (due to auditing, tearing, or jamming, or running out of "ink", etc. - requiring **B**) and/or the paper is "manually" advanced (perhaps just on loading),
2. track how much tape you've printed<sup>**2**</sup>
3. when the next receipt to print would exceed tape remaining, ask the user to load more tape.

**B**

- Implement a memory store of N transaction(s) so you can reprint them.

The closest vb.net has to 'as Any' is 'as Object'. vb.net no longer has the Variant type.

<sup>**1**</sup> of [receipt paper](http://www.ncr-direct.com/ProductList/Company/Paper-Rolls/Thermal-POS-Paper-Rolls/US)
<sup>**2**</sup> There are [72 points](http://www.asknumbers.com/InchesToPoints.aspx) "pt(s)" to the inch

Comment: i think.Your saying about the paper quality. here i have large huge much of tape. so the problem is not in tape..i think you understand the question wrongly...

Comment: Use the # of points for each line you're printing (e.g. 12 pt Arial will print 1/6 of an inch - with no padding). You'll have to adjust leading as appropriate.

Comment: to calculate the height of your data existing so that there can be no waste? Whatever # of pts for the font size you use, you can calculate the number of inches (or fraction thereof) you have used.

Comment: can you give some coding to check this?

Comment: I can't tell you what you need to print. Only how to calculate how much space it will use. X # of lines at 12 pt = X/6 inches of paper.

Comment: i m going to print the invoice bill, length of the bill will vary based on the no.of products saled... so i can't set the paper height as fixed one..so i'm using roller printer. in that also it takes some default height if i'm not telling any height. so if my data length is smaller the height of page. it ejects more paper as page height. this is my case... is there any solution to solve this issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41153/discussion-between-elliott-frisch-and-satson)